# MVC Complex ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to build a sample MVC UI app using Kendo UI.
I have 2 multiselect widgets for airline names and airport names respectively and below I have a grid with airline airport data.

Now when I select airlines or airports in the multiselect, upon clicking a Fetch button, the grid should refresh.

I created a ViewModel named `AirlineAirportViewModel` for containing `List<Airlines>`, `List<Airports>` and `List<AirlineAirports>`.
I instantiate the `List<AirlineAirports>` in the Get action method of the controller and fill the other two lists getting distinct airline and airport values from the `List<AirlineAirports>`.
While posting on filter button click, I am able to get action parameters as 2 `List<string>` types which contain only the selected multiselect items
Instead of that, I want this action parameter of type `AirlineAirportViewModel` so that in future, I will be able to add more filter widgets and the number of parameters stay one only. 
Now, am I approaching this in the right way ? If I need the ViewModel as action parameter, where should I store the selected items from the multiselects ?

Comment: How are the views implemented? Could you share some code?

Comment: Hi, I have added the code here as a zip file. Thanks for replying....http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/general-discussions/viewmodel-with-kendo-mvc-widgets.aspx

Comment: Hve you tried out the approach they've pointed out? It seems it would be easier the that way and I think it would solve your problem

Comment: Thanks @Stargazer. Their reply solved the problem